# Cómo puedo hacer un llamado POST en Android con este tipo de json

Tags: java, android, post

estoy haciendo una aplicación con retrofit en lenguaje JAVA,
estoy acostumbrado a hacer llamadas con un json simple,

cómo este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código que aplico es este

```
public class Cuerpo {

//parametros
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

public Cuerpo(String username, String password, String nroConteo, String item, String nroSerie, String cantidadFisica) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
```

mi interface

```
public interface Conexion {

@POST("/jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ1201A_ORCH")
Call<Cuerpo> getDatos(@Body Cuerpo users );
```

}

y el main dónde hago el llamado

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);

            Cuerpo logerse = new Cuerpo(usuario, contraseña);
```

ahora me tocó uno mas complejo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta es, que tengo que aplicar en la interface para que pueda hacer el llamado total de todo esto:

{
"username" : "xxxx",
"password" : "xxxx",
"Deposito_Desde": "ADUANA",
"Deposito_Hasta": "JMINGE",
"GridIn_1_2": [
{
"Inicial__final": "F",
"Número_artículo": "SE36X361A0194  ",
"Cantidad": "1",
"Ubicación": ".",
"Número_lote_serie": "800004"
}
]
}

desde ya,

muchas gracias

edición

```
     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://quantumconsulting.servehttp.com:925")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);


    GridIn12 data = new GridIn12("F","SE36X361A0194","1",".","800004",
            "F","SE36X361A0194","1",".","800005",
            "T","1","SE36X361A0194","2","P2","T201C04");

    List<GridIn12> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    objList.add(data);

    Cuerpo logerse = new Cuerpo("xx", "xx","ADUANA","JMINGE",objList);


    Call<Cuerpo> call1 = conexion.getDatos( logerse);//acá es cuando se me pone en rojo
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<Cuerpo>() {
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá va el parseo

```
public class Cuerpo {
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("Deposito_Desde")
@Expose
private String depositoDesde;
@SerializedName("Deposito_Hasta")
@Expose
private String depositoHasta;
@SerializedName("GridIn_1_2")
@Expose
private List<GridIn12> gridIn12 = null;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getDepositoDesde() {
    return depositoDesde;
}

public void setDepositoDesde(String depositoDesde) {
    this.depositoDesde = depositoDesde;
}

public String getDepositoHasta() {
    return depositoHasta;
}

public void setDepositoHasta(String depositoHasta) {
    this.depositoHasta = depositoHasta;
}

public List<GridIn12> getGridIn12() {
    return gridIn12;
}

public void setGridIn12(List<GridIn12> gridIn12) {
    this.gridIn12 = gridIn12;
}

public Cuerpo(String username, String password, String depositoDesde, String depositoHasta, List<GridIn12> gridIn12) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.depositoDesde = depositoDesde;
    this.depositoHasta = depositoHasta;
    this.gridIn12 = gridIn12;
}
```

parseo de lo que contiene gridIn12

```
public class GridIn12 {

@SerializedName("Inicial__final")
@Expose
private String inicialFinal;
@SerializedName("Número_artículo")
@Expose
private String nMeroArtCulo;
@SerializedName("Cantidad")
@Expose
private String cantidad;
@SerializedName("Ubicación")
@Expose
private String ubicaciN;
@SerializedName("Número_lote_serie")
@Expose
private String nMeroLoteSerie;

//segundo
@SerializedName("Inicial__final")
@Expose
private String inicialFinal2;
@SerializedName("Número_artículo")
@Expose
private String nMeroArtCulo2;
@SerializedName("Cantidad")
@Expose
private String cantidad2;
@SerializedName("Ubicación")
@Expose
private String ubicaciN2;
@SerializedName("Número_lote_serie")
@Expose
private String nMeroLoteSerie2;


//tercero
//segundo
@SerializedName("Inicial__final")
@Expose
private String inicialFinal3;
@SerializedName("Lineas_relacionadas")
@Expose
private String lineasRelacionadas;
@SerializedName("Número_artículo")
@Expose
private String nMeroArtCulo3;
@SerializedName("Cantidad")
@Expose
private String cantidad3;
@SerializedName("Ubicación")
@Expose
private String ubicaciN3;
@SerializedName("Numero_lote_serie")
@Expose
private String nMeroLoteSerie3;


public String getInicialFinal() {
    return inicialFinal;
}

public void setInicialFinal(String inicialFinal) {
    this.inicialFinal = inicialFinal;
}

public String getNMeroArtCulo() {
    return nMeroArtCulo;
}

public void setNMeroArtCulo(String nMeroArtCulo) {
    this.nMeroArtCulo = nMeroArtCulo;
}

public String getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public String getUbicaciN() {
    return ubicaciN;
}

public void setUbicaciN(String ubicaciN) {
    this.ubicaciN = ubicaciN;
}

public String getNMeroLoteSerie() {
    return nMeroLoteSerie;
}

public void setNMeroLoteSerie(String nMeroLoteSerie) {
    this.nMeroLoteSerie = nMeroLoteSerie;
}

public GridIn12(String inicialFinal, String nMeroArtCulo, String cantidad, String ubicaciN, String nMeroLoteSerie,
                String inicialFinal2, String nMeroArtCulo2, String cantidad2, String ubicaciN2, String nMeroLoteSerie2,
                String inicialFinal3, String lineasRelacionadas, String nMeroArtCulo3, String cantidad3, String ubicaciN3, String nMeroLoteSerie3) {

    this.inicialFinal = inicialFinal;
    this.nMeroArtCulo = nMeroArtCulo;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.ubicaciN = ubicaciN;
    this.nMeroLoteSerie = nMeroLoteSerie;
    this.inicialFinal2 = inicialFinal2;
    this.nMeroArtCulo2 = nMeroArtCulo2;
    this.cantidad2 = cantidad2;
    this.ubicaciN2 = ubicaciN2;
    this.nMeroLoteSerie2 = nMeroLoteSerie2;
    this.inicialFinal3 = inicialFinal3;
    this.lineasRelacionadas = lineasRelacionadas;
    this.nMeroArtCulo3 = nMeroArtCulo3;
    this.cantidad3 = cantidad3;
    this.ubicaciN3 = ubicaciN3;
    this.nMeroLoteSerie3 = nMeroLoteSerie3;
}
```

la interface

```
public interface Conexion {




@POST("//jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0801A_ORCH")
Call<Cuerpo> getDatos(@Body   final List<GridIn12>users );
```

}

y el llamado en el main

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://quantumconsulting.servehttp.com:925")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Conexion conexion = retrofit.create(Conexion.class);


    GridIn12 data = new GridIn12("F","SE36X361A0194","1",".","800004",
            "F","SE36X361A0194","1",".","800005",
            "T","1","SE36X361A0194","2","P2","T201C04");

    List<GridIn12> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    objList.add(data);

    Cuerpo logerse = new Cuerpo("xx", "xx","ADUANA","JMINGE",objList);


    Call<Cuerpo> call1 = conexion.getDatos( logerse);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<Cuerpo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Cal
```

Comment: Lo ideal es tener una clase POJO que tenga todas las propiedades de la respuesta. En un modelo relacional, puede haber propiedades de un POJO que sean a su vez otros POJOs. Así, harás tu llamada como haces aquí: `Call<Cuerpo> getDatos(@Body Cuerpo users );` cambiando `Cuerpo` por el nombre de la clase POJO correspondiente. Dicho eso, es extraña esta propiedad en tu JSON:`GridIn_1_2`, ¿qué representa eso exactamente? ¿tienes una entidad llamada así en tu modelo de datos?

Comment: hola! justamente lo que aparece en  `JSON:GridIn_1_2`, es lo que me complica, eso representa datos que son escaneados por un codigo de barras, eso lo necesito para que el response de determinada respuesta, pero sí yo ya armé toda la estructura pojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es sumamente sencilla. En formato JSON los corchetes o parentesis cuadrados representan listas de objetos. Por lo tanto tu clase en JAVA debe implementar una lista del objeto en cuestion.

```
public class Cuerpo {

    //parametros
    @Expose @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("password") 
    private String password;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("Deposito_Desde") 
    private String despositoDesde;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("Deposito_Hasta") 
    private String depositoHasta;

    @Expose @SerializedName("GridIn_1_2")
    private List<Grid_1_2> codigosList;
}

class Grid_1_2{
    @Expose @SerializedName("Inicial__Final")
    private String inicialFinal;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("Número_articulo")
    private String numeroArticulo;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("Cantidad")
    private String cantidad;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("Ubicación")
    private String ubicacion;
    
    @Expose @SerializedName("Número_lote_serie")
    private String numeroLoteSerie;
    
    
}
```

La lista que cree es codigosList, esta almacenará siempre una lista de objetos del mismo tipo. Prueba cambiar tambien el tipo de lista por ejemplo con ArrayList.  No inclui los set y get pero recuerda colocarlos.

Además en la interface conexion debes de actualizar los parametros

```
@POST("//jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0801A_ORCH")
Call<Cuerpo> getDatos(@Body   final List<GridIn12>users );
```

El codigo anterior te genera el error porque el BODY es una lista de GridIn12. Por lo que colocaste en postman deberia ser simplemente colocar el objeto Cuerpo.

En el Call<?> <<-- Aqui deberias de colocar el objeto que se devuelve en la consulta post.

EN palabras simples, el Body es el request del post y lo que colocas dentro del Call es la respuesta o result.

Cambia esto:

```
@POST("//jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0801A_ORCH")
Call<Cuerpo> getDatos(@Body   final List<Cuerpo>users );
```

Es posible que no te devuelva lo que necesites pero esto es porque según lo que colocaste en postman, el servicio post retorna un objeto diferente.

Comment: hola! sisi esa parte la tengo, lo que no logro hacer es en la hora del llamado en retrofit, te cuento que en esas dos clases que  me mostras, les hice un constructor, e hice un llamado del mismo, pero a la hora del llamado en el main me tira error,

me quedó asi.

Comment: mejor lo pongo en el pie de mi consulta

Comment: Coloca el cursor sobre lo que se marca en rojo, captura la pantalla o escribe que te dice Android Studio al respecto.

Comment: si he intentado los cambios que sugiere, pero no me a funcionado, al ejecutar la aplicacion se me cierra y de debug justamente me dice que el problema es esa linea

Comment: Puedes actualizar la pregunta con los objetos Cuerpo y GrinIn12.

Comment: ahi lo actualicé, te agradezco mucho la ayuda

Comment: recién amplie la respuesta. Revisala. Te falta bastante por aprender, te recomiendo tambien revisar hilt o dagger o incluso podrias implementar un patron de singlenton para mejorar el proyecto. Ademas busca como puedes implementar llamados asincronos, puedes implementar async task o Threads, yo me pase a rxjava pero luego me pase a coroutinas de kotlin. Son recomendaciones si quieres implementar proyectos más grandes.

Comment: gracias! voy a investigar lo que me dices,

Comment: Con gusto @G.Capovi. Recuerda si mi respuesta te sirvió puntua para ayudar a otros a encontrar esta y muchas más respuestas a preguntas. 

Para puntuar presiona flecha hacia arriba al lado de mi respuesta.